# How to persist keeping the info in the Session["Stuff"]?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, session

When the user makes selection and clicks a button, I call to:

```
public ActionResult Storage(String data)
{
  Session["Stuff"] = data;
  return null;
}
```

Then, I redirect them to another page where the data is accessed by

```
@Session["Stuff"]
```

This far, I'm happy. What I do next is that upon a click on a button on the new page, I perform a call to:

```
public ActionResult Pdfy()
{
  Client client = new Client();
  byte[] pdf = client.GetPdf("http://localhost:1234/Controller/SecondPage");
  client.Close();
  return File(pdf, "application/pdf", "File.pdf");
}
```

Please note that the PDFization itself works perfectly well. The problem is that when I access the second page a second time (it's beeing seen by the user and looks great both in original and on reload), it turns out that *Session["Stuff"]* suddenly is *null*!

Have I started a new session by the recall?
How do I persistently retain *data* stored in *Session["Stuff"]* before?

Comment: You could always use cookies. A bit more scalable and easier to debug (with the help of built-in developer tools)

Comment: When you use "Client" object and call client.GetPdf, you are starting automatically a new session different from current. This is the reason for the null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're simply storing string data (as would be indicated by your method signature) in an MVC application, don't.

It's far easier to pass the data as a query parameter to each method that needs it. It's far easier to manage and doesn't rely on Session sticky-ness.

To generate the appropriate links, you can pass `data` to your views and use `Html.ActionLink` to generate your links with the appropriate parameter data.

Comment: Is there a way to retain the state of the session anyway? I'm not happy to rewrite the whole model of information exchange in this particular case so I'm willing to cheat.   :)   (I chose not to use query string in case the data chunk would grew big.) Also, what about the M-aspect in MVC? Shouldn't one prefer to keep the data in some kind of model thingy on server side?

Answer (score 2):

Here's several reasons why the session variable could return `null`:

- `null` is passed into `Storage`
- Some other code sets `Session["Stuff"]` to `null`
- The session times out
- Something calls `Session.Clear()` (or `Session.Abandon()`)
- The underlying AppPool is restarted on the server
- Your web server is farmed and session state is not distributed properly

The first two can be discovered by debugging.